# Why does Alt code 12 appear as a question mark in Firefox?

Tags: unicode

In IE, alt code 12, which is supposed to be the female symbol, appears as a question mark. 
I have tried clicking the 'View' button in the menu bar, clicking 'Character Encoding', then choosing 'Unicode (UTF-8)', which I've been told would help. But it still shows up as the question mark. I have tried inserting the <*div*> tags around the character like so: <*div style="Unicode"*> and <*/div*>, but to no avail. And I have recently downloaded/switched to Firefox web browser and tried everything previously mentioned with the new browser. It has not helped. What should I do?

Comment: Which font does Firefox use? Is it the same as IE?

Comment: I do not know, but on my screen the two fonts look different.

Comment: Right click -> inspect element. Or force them to use the same font (`style="font-family:Arial;"`)

Comment: I checked 'Tools' -> 'Options' -> 'Content' on menu bar and the Default font is set to Times New Roman. edit: I did what you suggested Juhana - I found where it says 'Fonts'. It is Arial.

Comment: If you're typing Alt+0012, you're generating ASCII character #12, Device Control 2, whose representation as ♀, if any, is for historical reasons and, as you've learned, cannot be relied upon. The glyph you seek may be found at Unicode code point U+2640, and is there known as "FEMALE SIGN"; use a character mapper or your favorite Unicode-capable text editor (Emacs: `C-x 8 RET female sign RET`) to insert that code point, and you'll see it properly represented in any font which includes the glyph.

Comment: this is a really great article about unicode that will hopefully explain why this isn't working right for you: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Aaron - I'm a little confused about what you are saying. Is "Unicode code point U+2640" a sequence of buttons that can be pressed on the keyboard for it to appear?

Comment: Dr Cord - thank you I hope I find it somewhere in there

Comment: I am not typing Alt+0012, rather, Alt+12.

Comment: Which program are you using for creating and editing the HTML document?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela  I don't know about the program or if there is a way to find out about it... wish I knew

Answer (score 2):

There are no “alt codes” in HTML documents. If you type Alt 12 in a Windows program , it typically inserts the byte 12, which is interpreted as ♀ U+2640 FEMALE SIGN if the character encoding is Windows Code Page 850. In an HTML document, it won’t have such a meaning, unless you declare cp-850 (aka. IBM-850) as the encoding and the browser supports it.

The safe way is to save your HTML file as UTF-8 encoded and declare it as so encoded. If this is not possible for some reason, use the character reference `&#x2640;` for FEMALE SIGN.

Comment: I must have forgotten to mention that I am working with CSS. Is it a form of HTML?

Comment: @user3033662, no, CSS is not a form of HTML, and CSS has nothing to do with issue. CSS may affect the specific graphic appearance of a character, but it does not change the identity of characters.

Comment: hmm...okay.  I still do not know what I am doing wrong, if anything. Most of the content that is brought up in these comments don't register for me.

Comment: @user3033662 What people are trying to say is **don't use ALT+12** but `&#x2640;` instead. It's really not any more complicated than that.

Comment: @Juhana, no, there is nothing wrong with using Alt 12. You just need to select UTF-8 as the encoding.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but is &#x2640; a sequence of buttons one must press while holding down another one such as Alt or Shift??

Comment: @Juhana, I tried selecting UTF-8 as encoding but it still showed up as a question mark.

Comment: @user3033662, I asked about the program you use to create and edit HTML documents. If you cannot answer that, there is little hope for finding a way to solve your problem. The probable explanation is that the page has not been saved as UTF-8 encoded, and in that case, it cannot help to make Firefox interpret as UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, I've accidentally forgotten this..          I don't know what program it is exactly, because it is for public use for any person who creates an account on the website.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! Another user on the site that I was on helped me out with this problem, though. She said for me to type in a pattern of buttons like so: &#2640 (like the code above in one other comment), submit it, and it appears as the symbol of choice.  I'm sorry that I couldn't understand before - I feel so dumb  >.<